# Pandas Question about axis = 0 and axis = 1

Tags: python, pandas

Basically I know in Python axis = 0 means row, and axis = 1 means the column.

`df.isnull().sum(axis = 0)` summarize the number of missing values in a column, but
`df.drop(column, axis = 1)` means to drop out a column.

So I am quite confused that when does axis = 0 means the rows and why does the second code not using axis = 0?

Answer (score 2):

`.sum()` is applied **along** an axis whereas `.drop()` is applied **to** an axis.

`df.isnull().sum(axis = 0)` returns the sum of all null cells along axis 0 (rows/indices), meaning one value per column.

`df.drop(column, axis = 1)` drops `column` belonging to axis 1.